# how to assign AngularJS2 response object to class object

Tags: angular

I am working on a project in angularJS2 and using $http with observable to parse the JSON from  rest API and here is my code.

**Service:**

```
getSingleKey(id:any){

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('content-Type','application/json');

    return this.http.get(
        'http://192.168.1.59/keyapp/api/getKeyspiration/'+id+'.json'
        ).map(res => res.json());
```

}

**Component:**

```
private dataKey: Object = {};

this.keyService.getSingleKey(this.id)
      .subscribe( 

        data=> 
      {
          console.log(data.data),
          this.dataKey=data.data
      },
      error=>console.log(error)
      );
```

console.log(this.dataKey);

and i am getting the following response:

```
GET 
localhost/keyapp/api/getKeyspiration/15.json [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 398ms]
```

// response for  console.log(data.data)

```
Object { k_id: 15, k_u_id: 5, k_type: 3, k_title: "vaibhav", k_text: "", k_data: "2024067187.png", k_thumb: "", k_added_date: "2016-11-24T06:10:23+0000" }

// response for  console.log(this.dataKey)

Object {  }
```

In short, I am getting the response data but how can i assign the response object to my class object, Am i missing something in my code. thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What "class object" are you talking about?

Comment: Here we go again. Your `console.log(this.dataKey);` is called synchronously, immediately after you've sent your HTTP request by calling subscribe(). So yes, at this point, you haven't received anything yet. Your `console.log(data.data)` , which is where it should be, in the asynchronous callback function, shows that everything is fine. So where is the problem?

Comment: thank you very much, i understood that there is problem with my concept.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i am talking about console.log(this.dataKey);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JBNizet mentioned the problem in the comment section, you are logging a value which you are expecting asynchronously.

Your `getSingleKey()` method is an async method, meaning you can't guess when the response will arrive (network speed etc.).

You must do whatever you plan to do with the response, inside the callback of the async function:

```
private dataKey: Object = {};

this.keyService.getSingleKey(this.id)
      .subscribe( 

        data=> 
      {
          console.log(data.data),
          this.dataKey=data.data;
          console.log(this.dataKey); //will be defined since it is in the async functions
          //callback scope, so do whatever you want to do with this.dataKey here
      },
      error=>console.log(error)
      );
console.log(this.dataKey); //will be undefined since it is out of the async functions callback scope
```

Comment: thank you so much, that's work for me. Your answer was conceptual thanks for that.